# Remove " from start of documents in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection like this:

```
name: 'john'
family: '"smith"'
```

i want to remove `"` from first and end of family, for example convert `'"smith"'` to `'smith'`. i know should use update and regular expression like this /^"/, but how?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript example:

```
> '"smith"'.replace(/^"|"$/g, '')
'smith'
```

`/^"|"$/g` matches leading quote (`^"`) or (`|`) or trailing quote (`"$`).

Comment: Thanks, i used this: `db.persons.find({family: /^"|"$/}).forEach(function(doc){doc.family=doc.family.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');db.persons.save(doc)})`